# Irreducible Markov Chain invariant probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $X_n$ be an irreducible finite Markov Chain that starts at state $i$. That is $\mathbb{P}\{X_0 = i\} = 1$. Consider the first return time to $i$.

$$
T = \min\{n \geq 1: X_n = i\}
$$
and, for each $j$, the epxted number of visits to $j$ before returning to $i$,
$$
r(j) = \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{T-1} \mathbb{I}_{\{X_n=j\}}\right)
$$

a) Compute $r(1)$

b) Viewing $r$ as a row vector, show that $rP = r$

c) Show that $\mathbb{E}(T) = \sum_j r(j)$

d)Show that $\mathbb{E}(T) = \pi^{-1}$ where $\pi$ is invariant probability

---

Attempt:
a)
$r(1) = \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{T-1} \mathbb{I}_{\{X_n=1\}}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{T-1}\mathbb{P}\{X_n = 1\}$ but $\mathbb{P}\{X_0=1\} = 0$ since $\mathbb{P}\{X_0 = i\}$.

$$
r(1) = \sum_{n=1}^{T-1}\mathbb{P}\{X_n = 1\} = (P)_{i1} + (P^2)_{i1} + (P^3)_{i1} + \dots + (P^{T-1})_{i1}
$$

b)

If $$r = \left(r(1), r(2), \dots, r(N)\right)$$ and

$$
P = \pmatrix{
P_{11} & P_{12} & P_{13} & \dots & P_{1N} \\
P_{21} & P_{22} & P_{23} & \dots & P_{2N} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
P_{N1} & P_{N2} & P_{N3} & \dots & P_{NN} 
}
$$
Denote the $i^{th}$ row: $(P)_{i}$

Then somehow we should get that
$$
r\cdot(P)_1 = r(1)(P)_1 + r(2)(P)_1 + \dots + r(N)(P)_1 = r(1)
$$

I think a) is fine but b) there's some missing parts and as well for c) and d).

Thank you!